# Purpose of pushing Docker Compose service images for private repos?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know the question may sound silly, but as a Docker beginner I cannot find out or imagine a proper answer.

I can fully understand why a single image, produced by a Dockerfile, can be so useful in offering reusable software stacks to the community. On the contrary, I cannot see so much advances in pushing Compose images for private repositories.

So I imagine to “pack” my entire web application, dependencies, source code, web server configuration files in a Docker Compose project, spin up a VPS and just do a `docker compose up —-build` to start it, without worrying about registry, tokens and permissions. This is awesome. Only local images and no dependecies.

Why would I pre-build and push my service images a part from saving some build time?

Comment: You could get the answer by find out why and how **Kubernetes** works. As for why is private repo, because most of situation (in production), the image already contains your project source code inside, you don't want it to be in a public repo.

Comment: So another reason would be using Kubernetes (which unfortunately I don't know yet)?

Comment: How does the source code get on to the target system, without having a source-code repository, credentials, and permissions?